# Importing a file (MultipartFile) and the process - Java/Grails

Tags: java, file, grails, file-upload, input

So I am trying to do, what I thought, was a simple file read and import. So the way my code works now is that I have a file stored in a folder on the server, select it, and import it. I select the file through a multipartfile:

```
    <g:form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" controller="fileManager">
        <label>Company Name:</label><input id="cname" type="text" name="cname" /><br />
        <label>Select a CSV file to upload:</label> <input type="file" id="newFile" name="newFile" /> 
        <g:actionSubmit action="importContactsFromFile" value="Import" />
    </g:form>
```

So what I want to do is to:

- Have user select a file
- Download the file to a directory on the server (input/output stream?)
- Read the file contents (CSVReader) and import into DB (this works)
- Possibly clean up file after

So I have a massive headache with that second step. I pull the file into a def variable:

```
def newFile = request.getFile('newFile')
```

How do I bridge this gap? Slamming my head over this! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to save the file as an intermediate step before parsing it?  Most CSV parsers (OpenCSV for example) will read from a `Reader` or `InputStream` directly.  So you can do something like:

```
def newFile = request.getFile('newFile')
def csv = new CSVReader(newFile.inputStream.newReader())
...
```

If you want to save the file, you can use the [`transferTo`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html#transferTo%28java.io.File%29) method:

```
def newFile = request.getFile('newFile')
newFile.transferTo(new File('newFile.csv'))
def csv = new CSVReader(new File('newFile.csv').newReader())
```

In that case, you'll have to ensure two requests don't overwrite each other by ensuring unique a file name.

You can find more information in the grails manual: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.1.9%20Uploading%20Files

Comment: Thank you - I have this a shot and was exactly what I needed (and much less costly in lines of code).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Import statement
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;
```

in your controller method :

```
CommonsMultipartFile f = params['newFile'];
if (f != null) {
   BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (f.getInputStream())
   // Do whatever you like.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Grails documentation uploadingFiles](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#uploadingFiles)

Try this :

```
def upload() {
def f = request.getFile('myFile')
f.transferTo(new File('/some/local/dir/myfile.txt'))
response.sendError(200, 'Done')
```

}

hope this helps